# Identify rocker switch

Tags: electrical, switch

I'm working on a custom switch plate/adapter thing to 3d print for my friend's light switches. He has several that appear to be some outdated rocker style switch, but I can't find them online to get specs for.

Here are a couple shots of them:
[image: Front angle]
[image: Side angle]
* The one on the left

Can you identify the model, brand, or even the proper name for this type of switch so that I might find information about it?

Comment: Those use the same standard cutout that the regular toggle switch does, which should be all you need for printing a custom switch plate.

Comment: The plate has a special lever built in that needs to actuate the switch. It was originally designed for the flipper switch and I need to adjust it, but I need to find the dimensions of the switch and the range of motion to make it work.

Comment: Or just swap out the switch?

Comment: Much cheaper to design and print a new style lever than to replace the switches, but that's a valid fix.

Comment: Um, builder-grade light switches cost about 75 cents each.  $3.00 if you get contractor grade.

Comment: Watch out for aluminum wiring if/when you do the switcheroo... those switches fit pretty nicely in the aluminum timeframe.

Answer (score 1):

All devices in the US are required to have Nameplate information. If you have someone pull one out, it should have the name of the manufacturer, current carrying capacity, voltage requirement, and part number. It may be very hard to read but your picture shows 3 of them and I'm fairly sure that information can be gleaned from them.